How can I get a callback from EurekaLog when it catches an exception?
I'd like to add a record of all clicks made whenever EurekaLog creates a .el file. For this, I'd need a callback from EurekaLog whenever it catches an exception, so I can dump all recorded clicks into my own log file. Does EurekaLog provide a way to do that ?
I'm using Delphi 10.3 and EurekaLog 7.7.8.
Edit : Brian pointed out the EurekaLog callbacks, which are exactly what I need. Unfortunately I cannot manage to register them properly, I always get the "E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'RegisterEventReproduceRequest' that can be called with these arguments" error. Here are samples of the different formattings I've tried :
procedure OkTestThis(const ACustom: Pointer; AExceptionInfo: TEurekaExceptionInfo; var AReproduceText: String; var ACallNextHandler: Boolean);

procedure OkTestThisOther(AExceptionInfo: TEurekaExceptionInfo; var AReproduceText: String; var ACallNextHandler: Boolean);

TWhat = class
    procedure what1(const ACustom: Pointer; AExceptionInfo: TEurekaExceptionInfo; var AReproduceText: String; var ACallNextHandler: Boolean);
    procedure what2(AExceptionInfo: TEurekaExceptionInfo; var AReproduceText: String; var ACallNextHandler: Boolean);
  end;

I also tried using anonymous functions. How do I need to format this callback for Delphi to be ok with it ?
Documentation reference
Edit again : Actually, the what2 solution does work. I had so many different possibilities I miscounted the number of error messages...

There are various events available - even one to add a custom file to the report. See: https://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/index_events.php

Yes, OnReproduceRequest is perfect for my use case ! I don't know why Google didn't land me there, thank you !

@Brian that should be posted as an answer instead of a comment

@Brian Unfortuantely, I can't find how to properly register the callback. No matter how I format it I always get the error "E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'RegisterEventReproduceRequest' that can be called with these arguments". I will update the question.

I have a feeling you are asking a wrong question. Looks like you are trying to do some sort of "steps to reproduce" behaviour. If that is the case - why do you want to dump logging info into standalone file? It does not make any sense.
What you should do is include/bundle this info into bug report about exception. If you are OK with that - see "How to add custom information to a bug report?" in EurekaLog's How-tos.
If you still want to dump your info into a standalone file - well, there are events for that, such as:

OnExceptionNotify - called when EurekaLog handles an exception
OnBeginReportGen - called when bug report is about to be created

P.S. Regarding the "E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'RegisterEventReproduceRequest' that can be called with these arguments" error - different versions of EurekaLog may have slightly different arguments for events. So if you are looking at sample code for latest version and try to use it "as is" in older version of EurekaLog - this may not work.
The easiest way to fix this is to drop TEurekaLogEvents component on the form and register event from there. Proper arguments will be automatically generated by the IDE. Please note: using component for registering event handlers has some limitations.
Another way is to open EEvents.pas unit and look at event's declaration. For example:
  TELEvReproduceRequestProc = procedure(const ACustom: Pointer; AExceptionInfo: TEurekaExceptionInfo; var AReproduceText: String; var ACallNextHandler: Boolean);


I literally said in my edit that Brian had already pointed this out ?

Alex is one of the authors of Eurekalog.
